# how to assign a returned value from a function in a listener to variable and split it

Tags: javascript, angular

In the code posted below I have the method MousePosition which has coordinateFormat as an attribute.

The createStringXY() returns a string encapsulates the longitude and latuitude, and they are comma separated. The latter function
keeps providing the long and lat values as the mouse moves.

What I want to achieve is to assign the values generated from createStringXY() to a variable and then split the string.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  var mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    coordinateFormat: createStringXY(7),
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
    // be placed within the map.
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    undefinedHTML: '', //for what to be rendered when the mouse leaves map scope: values https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can create a new variable. Use `split()` to split the string.

```
var result = createStringXY(7)
var [long, lat] = result.split(",")    

// Or doing it in one line
// var [long, lat] = createStringXY(7).split(",")
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: but i want to have this value of createStringXY in a variable as long as the mouse moves. so as the mouse moves i want to have each newly provided value in a variable as you mentioned

Comment: Can I know what are you going to achieve? Maybe this one would help you out https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mouse-position.html